# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

already clear cache.

***I found these log in error_log.***

> [26-Sep-2019 08:21:49 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  The each() function is
>   deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81 [26-Sep-2019 08:21:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  "continue"
>   targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use
>   "continue 2"? in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426 [26-Sep-2019 08:21:57 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  The each()
>   function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further
>   calls in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81 [26-Sep-2019 08:21:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  "continue"
>   targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use
>   "continue 2"? in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426 [26-Sep-2019 08:22:22 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  The each()
>   function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further
>   calls in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81 [26-Sep-2019 08:22:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  "continue"
>   targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use
>   "continue 2"? in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426 [26-Sep-2019 08:22:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  The each()
>   function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further
>   calls in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81 [26-Sep-2019 08:22:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  "continue"
>   targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use
>   "continue 2"? in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426 [26-Sep-2019 08:22:28 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  The each()
>   function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further
>   calls in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81 [26-Sep-2019 08:22:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  "continue"
>   targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use
>   "continue 2"? in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426 [26-Sep-2019 08:23:07 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  The each()
>   function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further
>   calls in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81 [26-Sep-2019 08:23:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  "continue"
>   targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use
>   "continue 2"? in
>   /home/v1net/public_html/devmag/favelady/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426

How can i fix?

Answer (score 0):

`each()` function is deprecated in **`php7.2`** you can replace `each()` function to `foreach()` in `/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php` example below.

> From

```
while (list($name, $value) = each($directives)) {
```

> To

```
foreach($directives as $name => $value) {
```

> Reference: [each() function deprecated php 7.2 , magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233506/each-function-deprecated-php-7-2-magento-2)

**Hope it helps!!!**